# Update changes in Azure SQL Data Warehouse using polybase

Tags: sql, azure, polybase, warehouse

I want help regarding Azure SQL Data Warehouse, I'm using Polybase to ELT data from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 to Azure SQL DW. When we load data first time into DW no issues. But when we load data again/incremental load how do we upsert data?

Flow we are using

ASDL2 -> (polybase) -> External table -> (CTAS) -> Staging tables -> (transformation) -> dimension tables

Everytime data changes we reload data into ASDL2,
What is the best way to UPSERT data or we should also reload data into SQLDW?

Answer (score 1):

Because [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is not supported in Azure Data Warehouse, you need to use other means to load data from the External tables to your Stage tables. PolyBase can be used to load both initial and incremental data to the external table schema but it is how you perform the loading to the staging tables.

The following is a great tutorial on how to deploy this solution: [Using PolyBase to Update Tables in Data Warehouse from ADLS](https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/azure/using-polybase-update-tables-data-warehouse-adls/)

Once the data is loaded to the external tables via PolyBase in a ADFv2 pipeline, a trigger is called to execute an sp in ADWH to perform the load to the staging tables.